# ¿Cómo evitar que un usuario acceda a mi sistema sin estar logueado?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web con Django 2.0 y necesito controlar que al mostrar un template solo lo haga si el usuario está logueado, porque actualmente sin estar logueado puedo acceder al sistema escribiendo las URL a mano.

Entiendo que es comprobar si la petición request tiene un usuario asociado, pero no se en qué método hacerlo.

Mi **views.py**:

```
class CoinsPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coins.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def actualice(self):
        coinmarketcap = Market()
        for coin in Coin.objects.all():
            data = coinmarketcap.ticker(coin.cid, convert='EUR')
            coin.price = float(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['price'])
            coin.market_cap = int(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['market_cap'])
            coin.volume = int(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['volume_24h'])
            coin.circulating = int(data['data']['circulating_supply'])
            coin.change = float(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['percent_change_1h'])
            coin.save()
        return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy sencillo. Simplemente tienes que heredar de [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) en tu vista:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class CoinsPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    # ...
```

Al usar este mixin te aseguras de que todas las peticiones validen que el usuario esté autenticado. Si no lo están entonces se les redirige al login para que inicien su sesión. Por defecto, se usa la redirección usando lo que has definido en [`settings.LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL) pero es posible reemplazarlo usando `login_url` en tu vista:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class CoinsPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    # ...
```

Comment: Gracias! voy a probarlo y ahora valido si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Django te recomienda varias formas de hacerlo, es necesario decirle a cada vista que va a necesitar que haya un usuario para mostrar el contenido, o de lo contrario, por defecto llevarlo a la página de logeo para así poder ver el contenido. Estas son algunas de ellas:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class CoinsPageView(TemplateView):
    ...

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    ...
```

Esta es otra:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CoinsPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

Esta es otra:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .views import CoinsPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', login_required(CoinsPageView.as_view())),
]
```

Otra forma es crear tu propio mixin y hacer que todas tus vistas hereden de ese mixin. Esto solo aplica cuando hablamos de clases, cuando tus vistas son funciones, es similar, el decorador va directamente a la función